# Can we change system setting like airplane state?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a magic trick to put iPhone on airplane mode ?

I saw this : http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/bring-airplane-mode-control-ba.html

but it seems to be patched because I didn't managed to success with iOS 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot do** this with the Public APIs provided by apple.

This may be done using the unreleased Private APIs. But if you use these, you **cannot publish** your app on the store.

Answer (score 1):

Every single App Store app is sandboxed with entitlements.

What you are trying to achieve is simply not possible if you want to distribute your app in the App Store. Your App simply cannot get enough privileges to achieve anything remotely similar. You cannot set global settings that changes the behaviour of the system. Apple will never allow that.

At the best you can monitor the status of the network connectivity via reachability but this is pretty much it. Using **private API** = **straight app rejection**.